# Mysqldump database backup through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an issue when we are run a PHP script. Here, the file generated but the data did not get into the data file.

```
<?php
// Database configuration
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD","");
define("DB_NAME", "val");

// Get connection object and set the charset
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) ;
               
exec(" C:/xampp/mysql/bin > mysqldump --user=root --password= --host=localhost new_trcker > M:/db_valad/valadpk1_kima578_backup.sql");

echo 'exported';
```

here, only generate valadpk1_kima578_backup.sql file into folder location but not get all table and data that files.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: "`C:/xampp/mysql/bin > mysqldump`" -- Should this be `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump`?

Comment: @stickybit not working. just generate file but inside not getting any database table and data.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with mysqli

Comment: I suggest you the the output and fi the error that gives you :), pass a 2nd param to the exec() method and echo that after